# In CakePHP, can someone explain how __d() works, particularly in relation to how it is used in default.ctp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Sorry this will be a super newbie question.

In the `default.ctp` layout file, towards the beginning there are two lines.

```
$cakeDescription = __d('cake_dev', 'CakePHP: the rapid development php framework');
$cakeVersion = __d('cake_dev', 'CakePHP %s', Configure::version())
```

I've found the function for __d [here](https://api.cakephp.org/2.3/function-__d.html) which says it "Allows you to override the current domain for a single message lookup." I don't really understand what it means at all.

Additionally, I was able to do the same thing without throwing any errors by simply replacing the lines with

```
$cakeDescription = 'CakePHP: the rapid development php framework';
$cakeVersion = 'CakePHP ' . Configure::version();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its used for making your application multilingual.

You can use the command `Console/cake i18n extract` to extract all the text strings(which is the second parameter in `__d()`) into a pot file, which you can then translate.

See this for more information about `__d()` https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#internationalizing-cakephp-plugins

And see this for more information about extracting the strings into pot files
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html